# No Sound issue - Unalbe to detect sound input devide : Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, alsa, pipewire

Please help me to get this working for me.

I have tried all possible listed solutions but non is working for me.

https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Shring more information related to my system.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXTiM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL0hG.png)

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Rajesh.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general question: Did you try clicking on settings, sound and under OUTPUT device choose the correct option?